# Laravel command in cronjob will not executed correctly

Tags: laravel, command, cron

I've edited the crontab (centos) like this:

```
0 6 * * * php /var/www/site/artisan eex --update=true
```

The crontab (/var/log/cron) shows that the command has been executed successfully:

```
Dec 10 06:00:01 yyy CROND[19946]: (user) CMD (php /var/www/site/artisan eex --update=true)
```

However, the database has not been updated. If I start the command manually, it works fine:

```
[user@yyy energiems]$ php /var/www/site/artisan eex --update=true
> Updated 1 element(s) (43f70960-772c-11e4-92a4-57928d74f84f)
(...)
> Updated 1 element(s) (43fd1470-772c-11e4-b1f2-b58d1e3307a3)
```

Any ideas?

//edit: In addition to [Dwights](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27423517/2050629) answer, I also noticed, that the cronjob runs in the wrong timezone. I've adjusted it to Germany and it works fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find out where the location of `php` is on your server with the `which php` command.

Then, update your crontab to reference php at it's precise location.

Odd solution I know, but I had a similar issue and this turned out to be the fix.

Comment: Sounds good to me. I will try it and comeback later to accept the solution :)